# Reflection cannot find method which is implemented

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-phone

I can't figure it out why I'm getting exception about this line:

```
public void DoIt(object sender, MyEventArgs e) {
 //... other stuff
 Type type = sender.GetType(); 
 if (type.GetMethod(e.ActionName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance) == null)
    throw new NotSupportedException("Method: " + e.ActionName + " not implemented");
 type.InvokeMember(e.ActionName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance, null, sender, e.Parameters.ToArray());

}
```

I'm still getting error about method is not found, but I'm sure it is because condition in if-statement before invoking is false.

Comment: Did you try debugging it? One way is to set up a `for` loop iterating over everything a `GetMethods(bindingFlags)` returns.

Comment: What's the method? Is it *definitely* non-public? A short but complete example would help. Also, it would be more sensible to store the return value of `GetMethod` in a variable and invoke that, rather than using `Type.InvokeMember` which has to find the method again.

Comment: yes, it's definitely private. about the GetMethod(..).Invoke() - I'm getting Access Exception (it's windows phone app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's a [security feature](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/31698.aspx/1). I've encountered this previously in Silverlight - you simply *cannot* reflect on private class members on that platform. With Windows Phone being quite similar to Silverlight, I am pretty sure same restrictions apply there as well.